# How can I came to know whether selected day has already an event or not in full calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar for displaying the whole calendar view of the running projects and tasks but i want something like....
If admin selects multiple slots from day like (8:30AM to 12:30AM) then I have to check if any event is already present between that time or not

If it is present then I have to display a simple dialog box of changing status of all those tasks

But if it' not such then I want to display a dialog box to add a new event in that time slot

How can I achieve this ??
I have searched a lot but not getting the solution
Help me as sson as possible
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the options `eventOverlap: false` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/) and `selectOverlap:false` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/) to prevent the user from even adding or moving events to a location already containing an event.

This prevents them from doing that action at all.

If you still need to do it, you can do something like this (un-tested):

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
  //this should get you all currently displayed events which overlap the selected start/end times
  var eventsList = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", function(event) {
    //returns "true" (to include the event in the list) if it overlaps the selected start/end times
    return (start.isBefore(event.end) && end.isAfter(event.start)
  }

  //now you can loop through "eventsList" to perform your authorisation function
}
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/ for more details of the clientEvents method, which lets you select from the events currently displayed on the calendar.

Comment: But what I need is to let them select , and then want to check if it already contains events or not and based on that I want to display dialog box , but if i set selectOverlap:false then It will not allow me to select

Comment: but if you don't allow them to select overlapping events, then there's no need to do any check, because it will be impossible for them to select any area with an existing event anyway.

Comment: It is needed in my project at admin side , that admni can select all the events and authorize them in a single click

Comment: I don't understand how that's relevant? Are you saying the admin should select all **existing** events? Because the "select" callback is used for creating **new** events, nothing to do with clicking on existing ones.

Comment: If i am a user and I had added an event , there are 50 users and one admin , all the users had filled the timesheet , now admin wants to authorize all the events on a single click rather doing it one by one , and that's why when admin selects any slot which has already an event , then it should open a dialog for changing the status to "authorize"